# Splitting the current container in i3

Tags: i3-window-manager

I have only been able to do this accidentally, and I'm trying to determine how to do this intentionally.  I have two containers initially, with the screen horizontally split.  There's a web browser on the left, and a terminal on the right.  My monitor looks like this:

`[ firefox | terminal ]`

I want to focus on the firefox container/window, and either put something under it, or split it itself.  in i3 terminology I think I want the firefox container to become a parent.  What I want is this for example (left now split):

```
 ---------------------
 | firefox  |        |
 |----------| term   |
 | libre    |        |
 ---------------------
```

I have gone through the config reference and still don't know how to do this.  Probably because I don't know the technical (i3) name for doing this.  What is the name of this (since mod keys might be mapped differently in my config, than yours)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first focus your left container (firefox). For example:

> bindsym $mod+j focus left

Then you should split the container horizontally. For example:

> bindsym $mod+h split horizontal

From i3 user guide:

[Focusing containers](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_focusing_moving_containers)

[Splitting containers](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_splitting_containers)

Comment: It's worth noting that splitting does *not* immediately markedly change the appearance of the window that was split (i.e., it's likely to occupy the same screen real estate). It's only when another window is moved in the direction of the split window that the split will become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Editing file `/etc/i3/config` 
bindsym $mod+h split horizontal or
bindsym $mod+v split vertical
but if in virtualbox "File->Preferences->auto-capture keyboard" checked should ensure the shortcuts not clashing with the host OS (windows)
and after pressing it, nothing happens. New windows must be opened to take place after pressing those hotkeys.